# What is the relation between scattering amplitudes, fluctuations, response functions and correlations in macroscopic equilibrium systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, correlation-functions

In Kardar's book *Statistical Physics of Fields*, he mentions that that correlations at different length scales can be measured by scattering.  If its electric correlations, you would scatter light and if its magnetic correlations, you would scatter neutrons. (on the side, what other scattering experiments are preformed)

Here, he briefly mentions scattering amplitude $A(q)$ is proportional to the Fourier transform of the density of scatters $p(q)$ but, he doesn't explain with to much rigour why this is true. I believe, I'm correct to understand that $p(q)$ is any fluctuation away from $p(0)$, but why is $A(q)$~$p(q)$ in the first place?

Later on in the chapter he focuses on correlation functions as apposed to the magnitude of fluctuation.  I assume the scattering experiments are used to understand correlations so what is the relation between correlations and fluctuations?

Finally, I understand the mathematical derivation for the relation between correlations and the response function(both are second derivatives of the partition function) but is there an intuitive way of looking at this?

Overall, these concepts all seem to tie together but I'm having trouble seeing the big picture so I was wondering if anyone could explain the relationship between these 4 concepts:

- Scattering
- Fluctuation
- Correlations
- Response Functions